# validar datos con el request

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

ejemplo tengo una vista con

```
{!! Form::text('pagado',$pago, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese Cantidad $$$' , 'required']) !!}
```

- las variables las traigo de una base de datos $pago.

tengo un request (PaymentRequest.php)

```
'pagado' => 'min:2|max:10|integer|required'
```

- pues cuando ingreso una cantidad minima de 2 caracteres me valida y me arroja el error y no me deja avanzar con el guardado, osea todo bien.

entonces mi consulta es la siguiente, como puedo hacer para validar que lo ingresado en Form::text('pagado') si es menor que la variable $pago, no me deje guardar en el formulario??. que no se escribirlo en el PaymentRequest.php o dicha validacion solo debe estar en la vista?

------------------- formulario de vista (paid.blade.php) -------------

```
@section('title', 'Pagar')
@extends('layouts.admin_template')

@section('content')
@if(count($errors) > 0)
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
<ul>
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif

{!! Form::model('payment', ['route' => ['payments.update', $id],'method' =>'PUT', 'onsubmit' => 'return confirm("¿Estas Seguro?")']) !!}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Pagar</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
<div role="tabpanel">
<br>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('forma_pago', 'Saldo a Favor: $') !!}
            {!! Form::label('0', $saldo) !!} <br>
            {!! Form::label('forma_pago', 'Abono: $') !!}
            {!! Form::label('abono', $pago_abono) !!} <br><br>
            {!! Form::text('pagado',$pago, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ingrese Cantidad $$$' , 'required']) !!} <br><br>
            {!! Form::select('estado', ['pagado' => 'Pagar', 'abono' => 'Abonar'],null,['class'=> 'form-control']) !!} <br>
            {!! Form::checkbox('name', 'value') !!}
            {!! Form::label('forma_pago', ' Utilizar Saldo?') !!}
                </div>



                </div>
    <!-- Tab fin -->

<div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::submit('Guardar',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'] ) !!}
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos un ejemplo un poco más puntual (o real) de la validación que quieres hacer?

Comment: Te refieres a que puede haber un valor digamos 1000 en $pago_abono y 10 en `pagado`, si? dicho valor de `pagado` debería ser mayor a 1000 entonces para que se pueda enviar el formulario

Comment: la validacion es esa, la cantidad que valla a escribir en text('pagado') si es menor a la cantidad de $pago (variable traida de una base de datos) no me deje guardar el formulario y me muestre un error. que hago validaciones en request como que min:2, max:10 y cosas asi me funcionan bien. pero no se como hacerlo para validar esa cosa... sorry soy muy nuevo en esto de la programacion :( , pd: si necesitas una informacion extra que necesites me dices para adjuntarla y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: haa no, solo quiero validar el valor de $pago, ejemplo si $pago en mi bd dice 1000. significa que eso debe pagar. entonces si en el campo de texto   'pagado' si el pone 990, que no acepte el pago en el formulario y sale el error y no deje guardar. no se si me explico mejor ahora :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso tendrías que crear una validación personalizada, pues necesitas comparar con un valor en la base de datos.

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, en otra pregunta hice una amplia explicación sobre como crear un método personalizado de validación:
[Validación de tipo fecha en laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17654/validaci%C3%B3n-de-tipo-fecha-en-laravel/17658#17658)

En todo caso, para no repetir lo mismo, voy a mostrar otro método que puede ser también útil en esta situación:

**app\Http\Requests\Request.php**

```
namespace app\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
  public function validator()
  {

    $v = Validator::make($this->input(), $this->rules(), $this->messages(), $this->attributes());

    if (method_exists($this, 'validateBiggerThanDb')) {
        $this->validateBiggerThanDb($v);
    }

    return $v;
  }
}
```

**app\Http\Requests\PaymentRequest.php**

```
namespace app\Http\Requests;

// utilizar modelo o repositorio que obtiene el valor de $pago
use app\Models\Payment;

class PaymentRequest extends Request
{
  // métodos rules, messages, authorize

  public function validateBiggerThanDb($validator)
  {
     $validator->after(function ($validator) {

       // solo un ejemplo, tú obtienes el valor de $pago de la forma que te convenga
       $minPayment = Payment::obtenerPagoMinimo();

       if (Request::get('pagado') < $minPayment) {
         $validator->errors()->add('pago_minimo', 'El pago mínimo no es suficiente');
       }

     });
  }
```

Comment: gracias por salvarme otra vez mas!! jejeje. saludos.-